# How to find most important 300 words from set of 3000 documents using TF-ID?

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a set of 3000 documents and I want to select the top 300 important words from all the documents. I used TF-ID Implementation to get the scores for words across all the documents using TF-ID Vectorizer.

But I dont know how to use this Scorematrix to finally get most important 300 words ?

Is it a good approach to take the mean of the score Matrix along The column axis and then choose those words which has the highest mean TF-ID Score ?

Comment: What do you mean by important words? e.g most predictive 1-Grams for classification or what?